# Frontend receives 403 error when logged in if Django admin is also logged in

Tags: django, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to understand if I can be logged in as a user in both the django admin and frontend at same time in development mode. For some reason both won't work.

If I log out of admin I can request data and do some crud operations in the frontend. 
If I'm logged in the admin and logged in the frontend all crud like operations receive a 403 error.

I'm using django/backend nuxt/fronend and docker.

What do I need to do in order to have both logged in and working on data?

Answer (score 0):

Is the auth token set in the cookie? Try setting up an alias for localhost so that you can store cookies from 2 "different" hosts.

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-change-your-local-host-name

So 1 tab localhost:8080 and one tab myfakedomain.com:8080